# Microphone volume very low in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth, microphone

I’ve done the sound test under “Settings > Sound > Device properties and test microphone.”

I have tried two seperate Bluetooth microphones and both test at around 3-6%. If I hit the mic with my hand it jumps up to 100%, but the level that used to max it out with my voice now hits 3-6% max.

When I go to additional headset properties, and then levels, it’s at 100 and there is no option for boost.

I have tried my Anker Soundcore 2 Bluetooth speaker, which has a mic, and a BH-M9A AIKELA microphone.

I was using the BH-M9A to stream a few days ago. The only change I can think of that I’ve made to my system is deleted all of the config files for OBS to get the default settings back.

Any advice on what to do would be appreciated.

My computer specs are:

- **CPU**: Ryzen 3900x
- **GPU**: Gigabyte GeForce GTX 1660 Super Graphics Card
- **Motherboard**: MSI-b550-A Pro

I'm not sure on the ram or the hard disk, but I can figure it out if it's important.

Comment: I suppose you did make sure that you are testing the correct microphone. Is your windows Audio maxed out as well? Sound stupid but sometimes it's the simple things.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel and select the Sound applet. Then go to the recording tab and right click to select Properties of your Microphone

[image: Control Panel Sound applet, Recording tab]

Then go to the Levels tab from the Microphone Properties window and check the levels there

[image: Microphone Properties window]

Comment: The question asker states: "*When I go to additional headset properties, and then levels, it’s at 100 and there is no option for boost.*", so it appears they've tried your suggestion before and it didn't work. Do you perhaps have a different suggestion?